# How to scroll down flutter on chat page message view?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, scrollview, chat

I want to make the chat app I already built with the list view builder widget
But I don't know the logic for scrolling down when the message is at the bottom it will auto scroll
I tried this code on tap

```dart
                        setState(() {
                          messageDatas.add(
                            MessageData(
                              is_outgoing: true,
                              text: textEditingController.text,
                              reply_markup: ReplyMarkupData(
                                inline_keyboard: [],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                          scrollController.animateTo(
                            scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
                            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                            curve: Curves.easeOut,
                          );
                        });
```

But not full down, there is one message that is not displayed
What if I press the send button then full scroll to the very bottom?

Comment: can you provide simple code-snippet so we could regenerate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

use scrollAnimate outside of setState

```
 setState(() {
         messageDatas.add(
                 MessageData(
                      is_outgoing: true,
                      text: textEditingController.text,
                      reply_markup: ReplyMarkupData(
                      inline_keyboard: [],),
                          ),
                        );
                             
 });
 
 // after setState 
 scrollController.animateTo(
      scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
      curve: Curves.easeOut,);
```

Comment: I tried this but same result,

Comment: Then you can try this for a better solution.
Set the ListView to which the scrollController is attached to reverse:true so the page will scroll down every time the list gets longer